# Why would an Infura/MetaMask watch of a contract's allEvents() that works on Rinkeby fail sporadically on Mainnet

Tags: metamask, events, infura

I have some code that immediately sets up an `allEvents` watch for the contract, then leaves that running and uses it to handle various events generated by the contract. I've been running it on Rinkeby and it seems to always correctly pick up relevant events, including the results of transactions. However, on Mainnet, the events don't seem to be firing consistently.

```
var evts = rc.allEvents({}, {fromBlock:'latest', toBlock:'latest'})
evts.watch(function (error, result) {
   // handling code
});
```

https://github.com/realitykeys/realitycheck/blob/master/js/ui/main.js#L2959

What could be going wrong, and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Does it also fail with a single event? I remember having issues with chain reorgs in the past.